# Wait for end of sql loader work before execute sql script in unix bash file

Tags: sql, bash, wait, sql-loader

Tomorrow will be a work day for me =(. 
Colls, i need that sql script wait an end of sql*loader work in my -bash script. Is it right code below?:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -------- uploader.sh v 0.1 --------
# @echo; 

export NLS_LANG=russian_cis.ru8pc866
export NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='.'

ORACLE_HOME=/opt/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/bin
export ORACLE_HOME
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
export PATH

sqlldr userid=myscheme/0611@TEST_DB control=control_file.ctl LOG=test_log.log errors=100


wait #here i want to wait sqlloader executing

sqlplus userid=myscheme/0611@TEST_DB 10.33.19.13/test/DATA_UPLOAD/mysql_script.sql
```

I've read about wait function [here](http://unstableme.blogspot.com/2008/06/bash-wait-command.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell scripts, by default, only execute commands after the previous command has completed.  The only exception to this is when you execute something in a background thread using `&`.  So executing

```
sqlldr userid=myscheme/0611@TEST_DB control=control_file.ctl LOG=test_log.log errors=100
sqlplus userid=myscheme/0611@TEST_DB 10.33.19.13/test/DATA_UPLOAD/mysql_script.sql
```

will already do what you want.

However, if you want to use a separate thread so you can continue execution in the main thread, you can use

```
sqlldr userid=myscheme/0611@TEST_DB control=control_file.ctl LOG=test_log.log errors=100 &
pid=$!
#do other stuff
wait $pid
sqlplus userid=myscheme/0611@TEST_DB 10.33.19.13/test/DATA_UPLOAD/mysql_script.sql
```

That will allow you to `do other stuff` while the `sqlldr` command finishes.  The program would then wait for the `sqlldr` command to complete before calling `sqlplus`.

Comment: Ups, sorry, i didn't understand "if you put your sqlldr command to background with sqlldr &". Could you explain?